# Clicking on navbar, sub routes getting appended every time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I was trying my hands on react routing with browser history. Technically it works very fine. But the issue I am faceing is, the routes get appended everytime I click on it gets same path gets appended like,

by default if it is 
              `localhost:portno/postLogin/page1`, on second click it will become `localhost:portno/postLogin/postLogin/page2` and on clicking another link it will be become `localhost:portno/postLogin/postLogin/postLogin/page3` and so on

```
             `var Router = require('react-router').Router;
              var Route = require('react-router').Route;
              var IndexRedirect = require('react- router').IndexRedirect;
              var browserHistory = require('react-router').browserHistory;


              module.exports = React.createClass({
                    render:function(){
                       return(
                            <Router history={browserHistory}>
                                <Route path="/" component={preLogin}/>
                                <Route path="postLogin" component={postLogin}>
                                    <IndexRedirect to="page1" />
                                    <Route path="page1" component={page1}/>
                                    <Route path="page2" component={page2}/>
                                    <Route path="page3" component={page3}/>
                                 </Route>
                            </Router>
                           )}
                 });
```

My navbar page has the content linked as

`<li><Link to={"postLogin/page1"}></Link></li>

 <li><Link to={"postLogin/page2"}></Link></li>`

One thing I tried doing is 
making changes to link like below, but that gives me error, "React Router did not match any routes"
 `<li><Link to={"page2"}></Link></li>`

Where am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Try <li><Link to={"/postLogin/page1"}></Link></li>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start all you routes form `/` like
`<Link to={"/postLogin/page1"}></Link>`.
This way url would be appended to a base route and not to a parent one.